# What's wrong with this pseudocode for Forster-Overfelt's version of the Greiner-Horman polygon clipping algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, clipping

## The Problem

I'm trying to understand and implement the [Forster-Overfelt version](http://www.bcamath.org/documentos_public/archivos/publicaciones/PolyClip.pdf) of the Greiner-Horman polygon clipping algorithm. I've read [the other Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412973/greiner-hormann-clipping-with-degeneracies) about clarifying this algorithm, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

I know there's something wrong bc it produces the wrong intersection of two polygons even for a simple example that doesnt have degenerates:

```
subjpoly = [(0,0),(6,0),(6,6),(0,6),(0,0)]
clippoly = [(1,4),(3,8),(5,4),(5,10),(1,10),(1,4)]
```

which produces an intersection of:

```
[ [(5.0, 6.0), (4.0, 6.0), (5, 4), (5.0, 6.0)], 
  [(1.0, 6.0), (2.0, 6.0), (4.0, 6.0)] ]
```

Visualized it looks like this:

[image]

So this question is not about a particular piece of code or language syntax, but about **understanding the algorithm** and putting it into pseudocode. Thanks in advance!

## The Algorithm

The algorithm presented here is based directly off and should mimic the one described in section 4.2 in the Forster-Oberfelt paper, but obviously there is something I'm missing that's giving me wrong results.

### Part 1:

Start by looping both subj and clip and marking each vertex location as "in", "out", or "on" the other polygon.

```
for s in subj.iter():
    s.loc = testLocation(s, clip)
for c in clip.iter():
    c.loc = testLocation(c, subj)
```

### Part 2:

Proceed to loop the intersection points of the subj polygon

```
for s in subj.iter():

    if s.intersect:
```

#### Subpart 2.1:

Process each subj intersection by either unmarking them as an intersection or marking them as entry or exit, and do the same for the neighbour intersection point. NOTE: the algorithm explained in the article only explains how to mark the main subject polygon, but never says how to mark the neighbour, so here I'm just assuming both are marked using the same set of rules.

```
        mark(s)
        mark(s.neighbour)
```

Where the mark() processing rules is defined as:

```
        def mark(s):

            curlocs = (s.prev.loc,s.next.loc)
            neighlocs = (s.neighbour.prev.loc,s.neighbour.next.loc)

            # in in
            if curlocs == ("in","in"):
                if neighlocs == ("in","in")\
                   or neighlocs == ("out","out")\
                   or neighlocs == ("on","on"):
                    s.intersect = False
                else:
                    s.entry = True

            # out out
            elif curlocs == ("out","out"):
                if neighlocs == ("in","in")\
                   or neighlocs == ("out","out")\
                   or neighlocs == ("on","on"):
                    s.intersect = False
                else:
                   s.entry = False

            # on on
            elif curlocs == ("on","on"):
                if neighlocs == ("in","in")\
                   or neighlocs == ("out","out")\
                   or neighlocs == ("on","on"):
                    s.intersect = False
                else:
                    # label opposite of neighbour
                    # NOTE: this is not specified in the article,
                    # but one cannot take the opposite of the neighbour's entry flag
                    # if the neighbour hasn't been marked yet,
                    # thus the decision to mark the neighbour first
                    mark(s.neighbour)
                    s.entry = not s.neighbour

            # partial exit
            elif curlocs == ("in","on")\
                 or curlocs == ("on","out"):
                s.entry = False

            # partial entry
            elif curlocs == ("on","in")\
                 or curlocs == ("out","on"):
                s.entry = True

            # normal exit
            elif curlocs == ("in","out"):
                s.entry = False

            # normal entry
            elif curlocs == ("out","in"):
                s.entry = True
```

#### Subpart 2.2:

Finally make sure curr and neighbour dont have same entry or exit flags; if they do disable their intersection flag and change the location flags.

```
        if s.entry and s.neighbour.entry:
            s.intersect = False
            s.neighbour.intersect = False
            s.loc = "in"
        elif not s.entry and not s.neighbour.entry:
            s.intersect = False
            s.neighbour.intersect = False
            s.loc = "out"
```

## Bonus Question

A bonus-question is how to make this algorithm support both union and intersection operations since the original Greiner algorithm's support for union was by simply inverting the initial entry/exit flag, but this Forster algorithm doesn't use such a flag?

Comment: How exactly is it broken? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide a clearer description of the problem.

Comment: I've now updated the post on how I know it's broken, but there's no clear pattern on how it differs from what I expect because that's different for any polygon I give it. I will try to update with a "minimal example" later, but it is essential that all parts of the pseudocode are included so it can be checked and verified.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I made another edit where I made the whole post clearer, and broke the algorithm up into sections instead of a single codeblock, so that people can more easily review and identify problems with different parts of the algorithm. I can't make it any more minimal bc I don't know which part is wrong. Hope that helps.

Comment: Reversing the initial entry/exit flag in Greiner-Horman is equivalent to reversing all flags. By doing this one would trace the polygon which is on the outside of the other polygon and thus you get a union. 

I will have to consider your question more fully and will try and give a good answer later.

Comment: Also, the Foster-Overfelt algorithm is flawed in certain basic instances where there are no degeneracies, so I would suggest looking in to the following article instead
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010448510001478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more comment about unions instead of intersections. The main idea is that a union operation will proceed in the opposite direction as compared to the intersection operation. That is, if one is suppose to move backwards along a polygon for the intersection operation then for the union operation one would move forward and vice versa.

Now onto the algorithm: first, let's start with the outline of the algorithm. The algorithm I have here will only create one polygon per intersection operation, so you will have to adapt it to create more than one.

```
'''
  The following is an adaptation of the above Greiner-Hormann* algorithm to deal
  with degenerate cases. The adaptation was briefly described by Liu et al.**  
  *Greiner, G. and Hormann K., Efficient Clipping of Arbitrary Polygons, ACM
  Trans. on Graphics, 17(2), 1998, pp.71-83
  **Liu, Y. K., Wang X. Q., Bao S. Z., Gombosi M., and Zalik B, An Algorithm for
  Polygon Clipping and for Determining Polygon Intersections and Unions, Comp. &
  Geo, 33, pp. 589-598, 2007
'''
def clip(subject, constraint):
    subject, constraint = inside_outside(subject, constraint) #label vertices as inside or outside
    subject, constraint = poly_inters(subject, constraint) #find intersections
    subject, constraint = label(subject, constraint) #label intersections and entry or exit and possibly remove

    flag = True #loop flag

    #set our current location to the first point in subject
    current = subject.first
    #loop through our polygon until we have found the first intersection
    while flag:
        current = current.next
        #Either an intersection has been found or no intersections found
        if current.intersect or current.pt == subject.first.pt:
            flag = False

    #reset our flag for the new loop
    flag = True
    #If a point lies outside of c and there was an intersection clip s
    if current.intersect:
        append(clipped, current.pt) 
        While flag:
            #Entry
            if current.en:
                clipped, current = forward(clipped, current)
            #Exit
            else:
                clipped, current = backward(clipped, current)

            #Check to see if we have completed a polygon
            if current.pt == clipped.first.pt:
                #check if the polygon intersect at a point
                if clipped.num_vertices is not 1:
                    #remove the last vertex because it is also the first 
                    remove(clipped, clipped.last)
                #we have created our polygon so we can exit
                flag = .FALSE.

            #change to the neighbor polygon since we are at a new intersection
            current = current.neighbor

    #Check if one polygon is contained wholly within the other
    elif contained(subject, constraint):
        clipped = subject
    elif contained(subject, constraint):
        clipped = constraint

    return clipped
```

Now we can discuss the labelling. The following code is the loop for labelling intersections as inside or outside. It does not include the logic for determining inside/outside and is only the order of operations.

```
  #label intersections as entry or exit
  def label(poly1, poly2):
      #cycle through first polygon and label intersections as en or ex
      current = poly1.first
      for i in range(0,poly1.num_vertices):
          if current.intersect:
              current = intersect_cases(current)
              #Make sure current is still an intersection
              if current.isect:
                  current.neighbor = intersect_cases(current.neighbor)
                  #if the intersection is en/en or ex/ex
                  if current.en == current.neighbor.en:
                      current = remove_inter(current)

          current = current.next #move to the next point

      return poly1, poly2
```

And finally dealing with the various cases for labelling.

```
  #deal with the cases
  #on/on, on/out, on/in, out/on, out/out, out/in, in/on, in/out, in/in
  def intersect_cases(current):
      neighbor = current.neighbor
      #on/on
      if current.prev.intersect and current.next.intersect:
          #Determine what to do based on the neighbor
          #en tag is the opposite of the neighbor's en tag 
          if neighbor.prev.intersect and neighbor.next.intersect:
              current = remove_inter(current)
              current.en = True
              neighbor.en = True
          elif neighbor.prev.intersect and not neighbor.next.en:
              current.en = False
          elif neighbor.prev.intersect and neighbor.next.en:
              current.en = True
          elif not neighbor.prev.en and neighbor.next.intersect:
              current.en = False
          elif not (neighbor.prev.en or neighbor.next.en):
              current = remove_inter(current)
              current.en = True
              neighbor.en = False
          elif not neighbor.prev.en and neighbor.next.en:
              current.en = False
          elif neighbor.prev.en and neighbor.next.isect:
              current.en = True
          elif neighbor.prev.en and not neighbor.next.en:
              current.en = True
          elif neighbor.prev.en and neighbor.next.en:
              current = remove_inter(current)
              current.en = False
              neighbor.en = True
      #on/out
      elif current.prev.intersect and not current.next.en:
          current.en = False
      #on/in  
      elif current.prev.intersect and current.next.en:
          current.en = True
      #out/on  
      elif not current.prev.en and current.next.intersect:
          current.en = True
      #out/out  
      elif not (current.prev%en or current.next.en):
          if neighbor.prev%intersect and neighbor.next.intersect:
              current = remove_inter(current)
              neighbor.en = True
          elif neighbor.prev.en == neighbor.next.en:
              current = remove_inter(current)
          else:
              if neighbor.prev.en and not neighbor.next.en:
                  current.en = True
              else:
                  current.en = False
      #out/in  
      elif not current.prev.en and current.next.en:
          current.en = True
      #in/on
      elif current.prev.en and current.next.intersect:
          current.en = False
      #in/out
      elif current.prev.en and not current.next.en:
          current.en = False
      #in/in
      elif current.prev.en and current.next.en:
          if neighbor.prev.intersect and neighbor.next.intersect:
              current = remove_inter(current)
              neighbor.en = False
          elif neighbor.prev.en == neighbor.next.en:
              current = remove_inter(current)
          else:
              if neighbor.prev.en and not neighbor.next.en:
                  current.en = True
              else:
                  current.en = False

      return current
```

The above code has not been tested and it is not written for efficiency, rather it is written for readability and understanding.

Comment: this is perfect @lvleph! A clear structured pseudocode for how to handle degenerates. I would give you more credit points for your answer if I knew how to. It's the Liu et al algorithm instead of Forster-Oberfelt, but the important thing is that it looks like it works. Will post back when I get the time to try to implement and test this :)

Comment: Actually, it is the Foster-Overfelt. Foster-Overfelt mentions that the idea comes from Lieu et al., but that the idea wasn't expounded upon.